# Get a list of selected link in query just link checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, anchor

For dynamic checkbox selection in the div, i can able to to get selected checkbox id using below code,

```
$(document).on("click", "input[class='CheckFree']",
    function () {
        var allVals = [];
        $('.CheckFree:checked').each(function () {
            allVals.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        alert(allVals);
    });
```

But instead of checkbox now i want to use this anchor tag, while i click the link then it will be added and get the list of clicked links 
`<a class="CheckFree" href="javascript:;" id="cb-{{index}}">Add my Selection</a>`

I need an feasibility that we can able to do or not. Please suggest me.

Comment: we can do it.its possible.use just .CheckFree in place of input[class='CheckFree']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to add a class whenever a link is selected to indicate that the link is selected, then use the added class as a filter to find out the selected links.

```
$(document).on('click', '.CheckFree', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    var allVals = $('.CheckFree.selected').map(function () {
        return this.id
    }).get();
    alert(allVals);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", ".CheckFree",
    function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();// by this anchor tyag default action not occur
       $(this).addClass("Checkactive");// here we add a class to anchor tag which is clicked
        var allVals = [];
        $('.Checkactive').each(function () {
            allVals.push($(this).attr('id')); // here we push all clicked anhor tag links
        });
        alert(allVals.join(","));// by this all value come with comma seprated
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. i have returning "javascript; javascript;" only. I can't able to get an id.

Comment: see update previous i show href now i am showing id @Selvendran